# Wordpress functions.php does not affect the theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to customize my pre bought theme. What i try is, to have different menus for each page without using a plugin. Original theme has a function about navigation which uses walker class. here is the file in the original.entrepreneur theme. http://pastebin.com/TeT8hi7z.

I use Entrepreneur Child Theme. I want to use primary navigation in home page and turkish navigation in turkish flag. I added `functions.php` and I added the code below:

```
if (is_page('AOE Home')){
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'Primary Navigation' ));
    } elseif (is_page('turkish')) {
        echo "text";
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'Turkish Navigation' ));
}
```

But navigation elements stays same.  Can you help me to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with slug for the page in is_page('aoe-home') or any current slug.

Comment: usually this would be in header.php..if you are using a child theme create a new file header.php and but your conditional where you see the exisiting `wp_nav_menu()`